# Unable to deploy Ceilometer on Devstack (Ocata)

Tags: openstack, devstack, ceilometer

I am trying to deploy Devstack (Ocata version) with Ceilometer in order to test different telemetry configurations in a simple enviroment. My ***local.conf*** file has the following content:

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
HOST_IP=192.168.56.101
...
enable_plugin gnocchi https://git.openstack.org/openstack/gnocchi
enable_plugin ceilometer https://git.openstack.org/openstack/ceilometer stable/ocata
```

Once I run the ***stack.sh*** script, it seems that Ceilometer is correctly installed but when I check the available service with `service --status-all` they are not there.

Do I have to do anything else? How do I configure it? I haven't found documentation about it.

Thanks in advance,

Sergio.

**UPDATE:**

ceilometer-acentral.log

```
2017-11-21 14:22:48.823 28311 WARNING ceilometer.neutron_client [-] The resource could not be found.
2017-11-21 14:22:48.823 28311 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster network.services.lb.pool, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:22:48.860 28311 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster ip.floating, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:22:48.860 28311 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster switch.table.active.entries, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:22:48.860 28311 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster hardware.system_stats.io.incoming.blocks, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:22:48.890 28311 WARNING ceilometer.neutron_client [-] The resource could not be found.
2017-11-21 14:22:48.890 28311 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster network.services.lb.vip, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:22:48.890 28311 INFO ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Polling pollster radosgw.containers.objects in the context of all_pollsters
```

ceilometer-acompute.log

```
2017-11-21 14:27:57.652 29255 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster network.incoming.bytes, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:27:57.652 29255 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster disk.device.latency, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:27:57.652 29255 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster network.outgoing.packets.error, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:27:57.652 29255 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster disk.iops, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:27:57.652 29255 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster disk.read.bytes, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:27:57.652 29255 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster disk.device.capacity, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:27:57.653 29255 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster disk.device.read.bytes.rate, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:27:57.653 29255 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster cpu, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
2017-11-21 14:27:57.653 29255 DEBUG ceilometer.agent.manager [-] Skip pollster cpu_l3_cache, no resources found this cycle poll_and_notify /opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/agent/manager.py:170
```

ceilometer-anotification.log

```
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi [-] public endpoint for metric service in RegionOne region not found
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/publisher/gnocchi.py", line 372, in publish_samples
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     self._update_resource, resource_extra)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/publisher/gnocchi.py", line 447, in _if_not_cached
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     method(resource_type, resource, *args, **kwargs)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/opt/stack/ceilometer/ceilometer/publisher/gnocchi.py", line 430, in _update_resource
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     resource_extra)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnocchiclient/v1/resource.py", line 111, in update
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     data=jsonutils.dumps(resource)).json()
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnocchiclient/v1/base.py", line 49, in _patch
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     return self.client.api.patch(*args, **kwargs)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 229, in patch
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     return self.request(url, 'PATCH', **kwargs)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnocchiclient/client.py", line 35, in request
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     **kwargs)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 142, in request
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     return self.session.request(url, method, **kwargs)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/positional/__init__.py", line 101, in inner
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 513, in request
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     **endpoint_filter)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 856, in get_endpoint
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     return auth.get_endpoint(self, **kwargs)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 216, in get_endpoint
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     service_name=service_name)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/positional/__init__.py", line 101, in inner
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/access/service_catalog.py", line 228, in url_for
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi     raise exceptions.EndpointNotFound(msg)
2017-11-21 14:27:53.372 28802 ERROR ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi EndpointNotFound: public endpoint for metric service in RegionOne region not found
```

Comment: Ceilometer's documentation is found along with all the other OpenStack documentation at [docs.openstack.org](https://docs.openstack.org/ceilometer/latest/). If something isn't working, your first step is to look at the appropriate logs and see if there are any errors indicate the nature of the problem. If you're not sure what to make of the error messages, post them here (by updating the question, not by adding information in comments).

Comment: @larsks I have just added the ceilometer logs